# Sharepoint 2010 Exception error

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I perfomed in past days a migration of a web application from `Sharepoint 2007` to `Sharepoint 2010`.

I noticed some exception error on a page of the web site which where caused by one webparts on the page.

Appending the query string `?contents=1` to the address page in the browser I obtained the webpart giving the error and eliminated it from the browser.

Then on `Sharepoint` Designer I eliminated the reference of the web part from the page header.

After these deletion the browsing of the page now return the error:

```
Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.
```

After some googling without valid results I used `USL` viewer to get more error information and I found these extra adds:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.   
at System.Web.UI.FileLevelPageControlBuilder.AppendLiteralString(String text)    
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessLiteral()
```

Unfortunately in not the amount of info I would desired: as far as I can see the trouble is related to something wrong in content page.

Anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the error was caused by a spurious character outside the `<content />` tag: once I deleted the uncorrect char I didn't get the error.

Thank you